# Linking of collection view cells to new controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created CollectionView programmatically and passed images to them. Now, on tapping each image view I need to open the next each view controller respectively. I am newbie in Swift and I couldn't find the possible solutions for this in Swift 3.
I tried to do it for fourth 'todolistbutton' imageview but it showed me error. Anyone could help me out here in Swift 3 ?? 
My code is:

```
import UIKit

class MeBottomViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "guidebutton"), UIImage(named: "mybellybutton"), UIImage(named: "appointmentbutton"), UIImage(named: "todolistbutton"), UIImage(named: "duedatebutton"), UIImage(named: "myweightbutton")]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedme))
    imageArray[3].addGestureRecognizer(tap)    // Error: Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'

    imageArray[3].userInteractionEnabled = true   // Error: Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'userInteractionEnabled'


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 6
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cells = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cells",  for: indexPath as IndexPath ) as! SecondCollectionViewCell

    cells.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cells
}

func tappedme() {


    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToDoTableViewController") as! ToDoTableViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)


}
}
```

Comment: You want to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `UIImageView` but you trying to add them to `UIImage` ...

Comment: Can you please elaborate ur answer as I have given all codes out there?? I need to open view controllers separately on tapping each imageviews. I am new to swift. Plzzz....Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You dont need to set any gesture

```
    import UIKit

class MeBottomViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "guidebutton"), UIImage(named:    "mybellybutton"), UIImage(named: "appointmentbutton"), UIImage(named:  "todolistbutton"), UIImage(named: "duedatebutton"), UIImage(named:  "myweightbutton")]


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return 6
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cells = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cells",  for: indexPath as IndexPath ) as! SecondCollectionViewCell

cells.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]

return cells
}


}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 

 { 

let secondViewController =   self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToDoTableViewController") as! ToDoTableViewController 

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)


}
```

Comment: As he said, he want to add a tapgesture, if he has other content on his cell, maybe I doesn't want to launch his new controller on cell tapping. This solution is also a workaround

Comment: might be but he said he passing only images to collection view and in his code there is no other content.thats why I suggest him this.otherwise I am agree with your answer @ jimmy James

Comment: Of course, your editing is working as the same as mine :) Now, we just waiting for his feedback

Comment: Neither it showed error nor worked out ..... What is missing , I did same as your's code up there @ matloob Hasnain

Comment: I have add check for 4 row can you please click on forth row or remove if statement ?

Comment: remove this line if indexPath.row == 3 { and also closing bracket from end as well

Comment: I put check on 3rd row because you was adding gesture in 4th item of the array.

Comment: Nope... It doesn't work in my simulator. @ matloob Hasnain

Comment: did you set collection view delegate ??

Comment: Have you tryed my answer @Kajol Bhatia ?

Comment: Yes... I have set UICollectionViewDelegate @ matloob Hasnain

Comment: Please put break point on all delegate method and let me know if break points are working or not

Comment: I kept breakpoint at func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {     .... Its normal and doesn't show any error!!!  @ matloob Hasnain

Comment: we need to view code and storyboard structure because everything is good so why its act like this ?

Comment: Can you give me mail address so i could mail you screenshots directly ?? @ matloob Hasnain

Comment: matloob.hasnain@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to an `UIImage`. So you need to 
 add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your **`UIImageView`** as the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cells = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cells",  for: indexPath as IndexPath ) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
    cells.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]

    // Tap gesture
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedme))
    cells.imageView!.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return cells
}
```

Then just let empty `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post... It too doesn't work on simulator. It doesn't show any effect.... @ Jimmy James

Comment: Have you tried to put a Breakpoint on Xcode in the `cellForItemAt` method ?

Comment: Yes...I kept breakpoint at func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { .... Its normal and doesn't show any error!!! @ Jimmy James

Comment: Can you paste the code of the `tappedme` method in your answer ?

Comment: func tappedme() {
        let secondViewController =   self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToDoTableViewController") as! ToDoTableViewController
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
        
        
    }    @ Jimmy James

Comment: Whan you trying my code, did you enter to the `tappedme` method ? By adding a breakpoint in

Comment: No.. it didn't enter the tappedme method. It should be wrong as I am checking on simulator. Should I check on device(iPad/iphone) ??

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 

 { 

let secondViewController =   self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToDoTableViewController") 

?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

@  matloob Hasnain. Now it finally worked.I had to remove as! ToDoTableViewController.